# Как связать alghoritm и пользовательский типа данных в c++

Tags: c++

Со привычными типами данных все понятно, подключаем библиотеку #include alghoritm  и пользвуемся, все просто. А как работать с пользовательским типом данных, например:
        **Посчитать количество элементов контейнера принадлежавших прошлому году 
        (использовать алгоритмы count(), count_if(), accumulate(), ...).**. Соответственно пользовательский тип данных Date (3 поля - int d,m,y);

## Пример:

```
bool IsOdd (int i) { return ((i%2)==1); }

int main () {
std::vector<int> myvector;
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myvector.push_back(i); 

int mycount = count_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
std::cout << "myvector contains " << mycount  << " odd values.\n";

return 0;
}
```

## Не понимаю как и что передавать в функцию count, на изображениях классы List и Date:

```
int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

List list;
char fname[10];

cout << "Input fname:";
cin >> fname;
readfile(fname, list);

//Readfile считывает в список элементы, Head - указатель на последний элемент
//3 2 2016
//2 2 2016
//5 3 2017
//5 4 2015
//10 8 4030

int count = count(...);
return 0;
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Abyx Собственно проблема в том, что когда я использую count, первые 2 параметра указывают на начало и конец списка, а третий на то, что нужно найти. В примере это обычные числа. А в моем случае это тип данных Date, у которого есть поле Date. Получается, если я в count передам указатель на начало и конец списка, тогда что мне нужно передать в 3ий параметр, что бы он считал количество объектов с годом 2016(например)

Comment: Никаких "классов List и Date" я на ваших "изображениях" не вижу. Болтаются лишь методы этих классов. И что за "изображения"? Здесь принято приводить текст.

Comment: @Ant я подумал, что проще будет показать скрины, нежели вписывать код, что бы не так много материала визуально было. Всем не угодишь.
Верно подметил, методы, но я думаю в целом понятно что в теле класса находится

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто так использовать `count()` не получится. Нужно использовать `count_if()`, либо, если так уж приспичило - определить оператор `==` для пользовательского типа, который будет выполнять нужное вам сравнение - по полю года, например. Что-то вроде

```
bool operator ==(const Date& d) const
{
    return year == d.year;
}
```

Для каждой задачи - свой инструмент... Для этой `count()` - очень неподходящий.